# issue in logging with microlog in android

Tags: android, logging

When I tried to log data with microlog, sometimes it seems like some data are not logging properly. It means, sometimes those lines, using logger.info("..") are logged and sometimes those lines aren't logged.

However, I can see those lines from logCat all the time, means in LogCat is displaying properly.

I usually log the data using the microlog to the log.txt, the system default text file.

```
protected static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger();
protected FileAppender appender = new FileAppender();

PropertyConfigurator.getConfigurator(this).configure();

appender.setFileName("/myapp/log.txt");
appender.setAppend(true);

logger.addAppender(appender);

logger.info("testing");
```

microlog.properties

```
microlog.level=INFO
microlog.appender=LogCatAppender;FileAppender
microlog.formatter=PatternFormatter
microlog.formatter.PatternFormatter.pattern=[%d]:[%P] %c - %m %T
```

How can I resolve that problem so that all those line using `logger.info("...")` will be logged to `log.txt file` all the time?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to your problem?

Answer (score 0):

This could be a bug. Try to set the logging level in the code instead. If this is working, something is either wrong in your configuration file or it is a bug.

Answer (score 0):

It is working for me. Create a folder of your application before printing logs.

```
    new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/myapp").mkdir();

    PropertyConfigurator.getConfigurator(this).configure();

    appender.setFileName("/myapp/log.txt");
    appender.setAppend(true);

    logger.addAppender(appender);

    logger.debug("testing");
```